# Is it possible to throw an exception from an If statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception

I have an assignment that I'm working on and we are told to answer the question using Exception handling.
Here's the question:

The `validateShelveNo(String)` method receives the shelve number and check whether the `shelveNo` starts with ABC.
If not then the method throws exception error ”The shelve number must start with ABC ”.
Also the method checks whether the barcode ends with any numeric value from 101 to 120 , otherwise the method
throws “The shelve number must be within 101 and 120”.
When the shelve number met all requirements the method must return true.

and my answer:

```java
public boolean validateShelveNo(String shelveNo) {
    boolean test2 = true;
   
        if (shelveNo.startsWith("ABC") == true)) {
            test2 = true;
        }
    else
      {
         throw new Exception("The shelf number must start with ABC ");
        test2 = false;
      }
  
        String lastThreeDigits = "";
        if (shelveNo.length() > 3)
 {
            lastThreeDigits = shelveNo.substring(shelveNo.length() - 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < lastThreeDigits.length; i++) {
                if ((Character.isDigit(lastThreeDigits.charAt(i)) == true)) {
                    int digits = Integer.parseInt(lastThreeDigits);
                    if (digits >= 101 && digits <= 120) {
                        test2 = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The shelf number must be within 101 and 120");
                        test2 = false;
                    }
                    test2 = true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(" The last 3 Characters are not numeric");
                    test2 = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("shelf number has less than 3 characters!");
            test2 = false;
        }
    }
   
    return test2;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `try-catch`. You just [throw an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)

Comment: Your assignment says that your function should throw exceptions to indicate invalid inputs and return true otherwise. You are not throwing exceptions, you are returning false instead. Also your first catch block will never be executed, because there is no throw in the try block.

Comment: As far as I am aware, ___shelve___ is a verb in English. The noun is ___shelf___. Hence I suggest that the error message be: _The shelf number must start with ABC_

Comment: okay thank you Ill edit that @Abra

Comment: @Abra  would this be correct? public boolean abcMethod(String st) throws Exception

 {
  boolean result;
   
  
       
  if (st.length() == 20)
      {
              // do stuff with  input 
     result = true;
            }
             else 
    
   {
               throw new Exception("xxxxxxxx");
      result = false;
            }
   
   return result;
}

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the alternative java code.

Comment: done does it look okay?

Comment: @Abra Im sorry Im still new to this

Comment: Do you have any limitations on how to implement the method? Can you use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: So far we've never used Regular Expressions so I doubt that is allowed.

Comment: @Abra still with me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. Hopefully using only the parts of java that you know.

```java
/**
 * Validates the shelf number. The number must begin with "ABC" and must terminate with
 * a three digit integer number between 101 and 120. Method throws unchecked exception
 * if the supplied shelf number is not valid.
 * 
 * @param shelfNo - the shelf number to validate.
 * 
 * @return  true if shelfNo is valid.
 */
public boolean validateShelfNo(String shelfNo) {
    if (shelfNo == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null shelf number.");
    }
    int length = shelfNo.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty shelf number.");
    }
    if (length < 6) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid shelf number: " + shelfNo);
    }
    shelfNo = shelfNo.toUpperCase();
    if (!shelfNo.startsWith("ABC")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid shelf number: " + shelfNo);
    }
    String lastThreeDigits = shelfNo.substring(length - 3);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(lastThreeDigits); // throws NumberFormatException if 'suffix' not a number
    if (number < 101  ||  number > 120) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number not between 101 and 120.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

First I add *javadoc* comments explaining what the method does. Because it is a public method, anyone can call it, so you need to explain to them what it does.

The method can be called with any kind of parameter value, so you need to make sure it is not null and contains at least six characters before you check that it starts with ABC and finishes with a number between 101 and 120.

Since the method throws an exception whenever `shelfNo` is not valid, the method only needs to return `true`. When a method throws an exception, it doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. This looks much clean and understandable. I really appreciate it.